# Cannot Select/Copy paste information from Details Pane

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are no longer able to Select/Copy information from the List & Document Library Details pane
Nothing happens when we try to select or highlight.
Tried with different browser (IE, Edge, & chrome)

[image]

Can select and copy from the details pane in a different tenant 
[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In the modern experience, the detail information panel (right panel) for displaying properties of an item does not allow users to select any content in that. Thus, you cannot select and copy any thing in detail information panel. Users can only copy content in edit mode.

To work around this, you can switch to classic experience by clicking “Return to classic SharePoint” in the bottom, left corner of the page to switch to classic experiences. Users can copy field values including multiple-lines of text field values in classic experience.

Comment: It was working all these days and is still working in another different tenant 
Selecting and copy is possible from the information/details